# Audio element works fine in Safari but breaks in XCode Simulator (web view)

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, html

So I have an audio element in my HTML:

```
    <audio id="success-sound" class="hidden">
        <source src="sound/success.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
```

The sound is played on click / touch event. It works fine in Safari on my Mac, the music plays. I am creating an iOS app though with a web view where I ember my HTML5 app. When I try the app in iPad 6.1 simulator and debug the console, I can see this error:

```
INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

This is the line that's failing:

```
        var successSound = document.getElementById("success-sound");
        successSound.currentTime = 0;
        successSound.play();
```

Any ideas?

Btw, I have another audio element with a soundtrack which works:

```
    function startSoundtrack() {
        soundtrack.play();
        soundtrack.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            var audio = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                audio.currentTime = 0;
                audio.play();
            }, 5000);
        }, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems iOS has some limitations when it comes to HTML5. It appears to be difficult to have more than one audio element and play the second audio element while the first audio element is playing in the background.

I have solved the problem by using AVAudioPlayer instead, I use JavaScript to notify the view controller of the web view when I want to play a sound.